# SSIS 2008 r2 how to connect to FTP using SSL

Tags: ssl, ssis, ftp

Is there a way to connect to an FTP using SSL in SSIS. The FTP connect in SSIS is without SSL option, what to do if the option of buying is not an option?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a third-party tool with a command-line interface or API and do the transfer using an Execute Process or Script Task. Most of the time that's much easier than using the rather limited built-in FTP task anyway. [Many](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) [different](http://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Main_Page) SFTP [clients](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) are available at no cost.